# How to convert each line returned by url.lines on the fly?

Tags: swift

I want to browse each line of a large remote CSV file using `url.lines`. However, the file is encoded in `.windowsCP1252` and I get `String` containing erroneous characters.

The best I've managed is to convert the text to `Data` and then convert it to `String` again, but all the special characters are replaced by `?`.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://foo.bar/data.csv")!
for try await line in url.lines {
    let data = line.data(using: .windowsCP1252, allowLossyConversion: true)!
    let line = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
}
```

If the `allowLossyConversion` parameter is set to `false`, this always fails.

How can I correctly convert each line to `.utf8` on the fly?

Comment: "the file is encoded in .windowsCP1252" Maybe it isn't.

Comment: `URL lines` may be assuming UTF-8 encoding. If so, your attempt to convert is backwards. You need `data` to be using `.utf8` (so you get back the original data) and your `String` initializer needs to be using `.windowsCP1252`.

Comment: @matt If I load data with `URLSession.shared.data(from: URL(string: "https://foo.bar/data.csv")!)`, then `String(data: data, encoding: .windowsCP1252)` is correct.

Comment: @HangarRash It results with badly decoded characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an alternative that uses `url.resourceBytes` and recreates each line of the CSV file whenever a line break is encountered.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://foo.bar/data.csv")!
var line: String = .init()
for try await byte in url.resourceBytes {
    let data = Data([byte])
    let string = String(data: data, encoding: .windowsCP1252)!
    let character = Character(string)
    if character.isNewline {
        guard line.isEmpty == false else { continue }
        // Here we can process the line.
        line.removeAll()
    } else {
        line.append(character)
    }
}
```

Comment: Breaking it down byte-by-byte like this looks really slow. Have you tried using `resourceBytes` as an input as a whole? `String(data: url.resourceBytes, encoding: .windowsCP1252).split(separator: "\n").map { line in doSomething(with: line) }`

Comment: @Alexander `url.resourceBytes` returns a value of type `URL.AsyncBytes`, not `Data`.